# how to add a virtual extra line to a text file while reading it with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I am reading a text file in a for loop. I want to be sure that the last line is "LASTLINE" even if it is not in the text file. Is it possible to somehow append it to the iterator (which I think is `f` in this case)?

Code:

```
with open(filename) as f:
  for line in f:
    function(line)
```

I have tried

```
  for line in f.append("LASTLINE"):
```

but it didn’t work.

If it was a very small textfile I could transform it to a list and append an element.

Comment: what if LASTLINE is in the text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to add the additional line to the input passed to the for loop:

```
import itertools

with open(filename) as f:
  for line in itertools.chain(f, ['LASTLINE']):
    function(line)
```

`chain()` works by returning elements of the given sequence objects (lists, tuples, strings, file objects etc.) in order. When the first sequence is exhausted it moves onto the next, and so on until all sequences have been processed. Because it deals with sequences, the "virtual" line must be placed in a container such as a list as shown above (otherwise the individual characters comprising the string would be returned individually).

There is nothing wrong with this either:

```
with open(filename) as f:
  for line in f:
    function(line)
  else:
    function('LASTLINE')
```

which will process "LASTLINE" if the for loop terminates normally (no break or exceptions).